# Redirecting to new contact record record detail page is not working in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using the below vf page and controller class, but in the controller class redirection is not happening to contact detail page and lead detail page,remaing redirections are working fine.

## My VF

```
 <apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="LeadExtension">

          <apex:form >
             <apex:actionfunction name="initialProcess" action="{!Duplicatechk}" rerender="pbk,secondarySection">
             </apex:actionfunction>
             <apex:actionfunction name="secondaryProcess" action="{!CreateContact}"  rerender="pbk">>
            </apex:actionfunction>

     <apex:pageBlock id="pbk">
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!InitialLoad}" columns="1" id="initialSection">
 <H1>Are you sure you want to convert lead?</H1>
 <apex:selectRadio onClick="initialProcess()" value="{!FirstRadio}">
  <apex:selectOption itemValue="1"  itemlabel="Yes"></apex:selectOption>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemlabel="No"> </apex:selectOption>                
  </apex:selectRadio>

  </apex:pageBlockSection>

     <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!afterSelection}" columns="1" id="secondarySection">
<H1>Duplicate contact exists do u want to create again?</H1>
 <apex:selectRadio onClick="secondaryProcess()" value="{!SecondRadio}">
  <apex:selectOption itemValue="1"  itemlabel="Yes"></apex:selectOption>
  <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemlabel="No" onClick="secondaryProcess()"> </apex:selectOption>                
 </apex:selectRadio>

 </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock> 
 </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

======controller===

```
public class LeadExtension {
Public String FirstRadio {get;set;}

Public String SecondRadio {get;set;}

Public Boolean showmsg{get;set;}

public boolean InitialLoad{get;set;}

Public boolean afterSelection {get;set;}


Public Lead  lead1{get;set;}

  public LeadExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

   afterSelection = false;
   InitialLoad = true;    
   showmsg=false; 
   string id1=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');


 lead1=[select id,name,account__c,account__r.name,Email from lead where id=:id1 limit 1];
 system.debug('%%%%&&&&&'+lead1);

    }
    Public pagereference Duplicatechk(){
       system.debug('%%%%AAAA&&&&& Duplicatechk SecondRadio'+SecondRadio);
        system.debug('%%%%AAAA&&&&&  Duplicatechk FirstRadio '+FirstRadio);

        list<contact> contactlist =new list<contact>();
        contactlist =[select name from contact where email=:lead1.email];

        //afterSelection = true;
        if(contactlist.size()>0){
            afterSelection = true;
         InitialLoad = false; 
           //return null;
        }else
        {

   system.debug('enter creating contact after duplicate chk ');
     InitialLoad = false; 
     afterSelection  = false; 
     contact c = new contact();
     C.lastname=lead1.name;
     c.accountId=lead1.account__c;
    insert c;

     system.debug('creating for contact and oppty redirection ');
     if(c.id != null || lead1.account__c != null){
      Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
       lc.setLeadId(lead1.id);
       lc.setContactId(c.id);
       lc.setAccountId(lead1.account__c);
       lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
       LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
       lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

       Database.convertLead(lc);

       system.debug('creating contact after duplicate chk '+c.id);

       if(FirstRadio=='2'){

        PageReference p = new Pagereference('/'+c.id);
        system.debug('page is '+p);
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;
         }
         if(FirstRadio=='1'){


   PageReference p = new Pagereference('/apex/OpportunityVF?cName='+c.lastname+'&name='+lead1.account__r.name);
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;

            }  
             }
        }

        return null;

    }

    Public pagereference CreateContact(){

        system.debug('%%%%AAAA&&&&& CreateContact SecondRadio'+SecondRadio);
        system.debug('%%%%AAAA&&&&&  CreateContact FirstRadio '+FirstRadio);
         contact c = new contact();
        afterSelection = false;
        if((firstRadio == '2' && SecondRadio == '1') || firstRadio == '1' && SecondRadio == '1')

        {


 C.lastname=lead1.name;
 c.accountId=lead1.account__c;
 insert c;

 Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
 lc.setLeadId(lead1.id);
 lc.setContactId(c.id);
 lc.setAccountId(lead1.account__c);
 lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
 LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
 lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

 Database.convertLead(lc);   

  }
   if( firstRadio == '2' && SecondRadio == '1' )
    {
      PageReference p = new Pagereference('/'+c.id);
      p.setRedirect(true);
     system.debug('are you redirecting to contact page????');
     return p;
     system.debug('please redirect to contact page||||||||');

    }

    if(firstRadio == '1' && SecondRadio == '1' )
            {
    PageReference p = new Pagereference('/apex/OpportunityVF?cName='+c.lastname+'&name='+lead1.account__r.name);
                    p.setRedirect(true);
                    return p;
         }

      PageReference p = new Pagereference('/'+lead1.id);
             p.setRedirect(true);
             return p;
    }


}
```

Comment: check the flow using debug. there are many PageReference and retrun statment. Check if you are getting correct PageReference.

Comment: narendhar -- I would suggest you spend some time reformatting your code to be properly indented. Use the edit link to do so. This is really hard to read